# Update CoreOS in offline mode - is it possible?

Tags: update, coreos

Is it possible to update CoreOS in offline mode?

My CoreOS cluster does not have access to Internet, so is it possible to get the new CoreOS image and apply it as an update in someway?

Comment: You cannot even [use a proxy server](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/update-strategies.html#updating-behind-a-proxy)?

Comment: The thing is that I want to control the updates myself, e.g. read the release notes before applying the update. Is that possible?

Comment: If you want the best answer, you should always ask [your real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912). If you have Internet access, but want to control updates, that may have a completely different answer than if you don't have Internet access.

Comment: In the final environment I will not have access to Internet. Now, on my development machine I have Internet, but my cluster (running as virtual box instances) only has a private network attached so the nodes can communicate with each other, but not with the Internet, so my cluster does not have access to the Internet.